# How to change comment texts that has a specific comment_ID - Hook into comment

Tags: comments

Say, I want to change the comment text where comment_ID = 10 or 19. I don't want them to be updated in the database. Just in the frontend, it'll show a custom text instead of original comment content.

Is there any hook that helps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the `get_comment_text` filter. Here's an untested example:

```
/**
 * Override comment text for comments with ID 10 or 19
 */
add_filter( 'get_comment_text', function( $text, \WP_Comment $c, Array $args )
{
    if( ! is_admin() && in_array( $c->comment_ID, [ 10, 19 ] ) )
        $text = __( "You've Just Been Erased!" );

    return $text;
}, 10, 3 );
```

where the `\WP_Comment` class will be introduced in WordPress 4.4

For WordPress < 4.4 we would just have to remove the `\WP_Comment` *type hint/declaration*:

```
/**
 * Override comment text for comments with ID 10 or 19
 */
add_filter( 'get_comment_text', function( $text, $comment, Array $args )
{
    if( ! is_admin() && in_array( $comment->comment_ID, [ 10, 19 ] ) )
        $text = __( "You've Just Been Erased!" );

    return $text;
}, 10, 3 );
```

and this would also work in +4.4.

Comment: So, there is no way to solve this WordPress before 4.4 ?

Comment: Please check the updated answer @mukto90